# upgrade from lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 no Ethernet controller setup

Tags: networking, lubuntu, 22.04, ethernet

I ran these commands in the terminal.

```
$ sudo netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
    Destination
    Gateway
    Genmask
    Flags 
    MSS Window 
    irtt 
    Iface
```

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C Network
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci00000:03:00.0
    version: 03
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress nsix vpd cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:ce00(size=256) memory: fdfff000-fdffffff memory: fdff800e-fdffbfff memory: fd600000-fd61ffff
```

I started with a fresh install. I removed the partition from my hard drive and used a Ubuntu 22.04 live DVD to reinstall Linux on that hard drive. I still have no internet unless I use USB tethering. How do I get the system to recognize my onboard Ethernet connection? These are the results of `sudo ip a`

```
david@david-linux:~$ sudo ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
david@david-linux:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for david: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff memory:fd600000-fd61ffff
```

Comment: You've tagged Lubuntu and mentioned 18.04 to 20.04; an *unsupported* upgrade path that is documented to break the system. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last LXDE release, and upgrades to the later LXQt desktop is unsupported. If you read https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/ etc you'll read "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"

Comment: The *unsupported Lubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade* should not have broken your networking, as that is part of the base Ubuntu system, but I'd boot 20.04 *live* media & explore there to ensure networking is correct, the consider a re-install, as even if networking is returned, portions of your desktop system will remain broken (*Note: I've no idea if you found & followed the procedures on upgrading LXDE to LXQt or not, what packages you have installed etc, but a clean install is actually far faster, even unclean install maybe better*).

Comment: Which kernel stack are you using?  If you were using GA on 18.04, you'll be using GA on 20.04, if HWE on 18.04 you'll have HWE on 20.04... If your hardware is old (*maybe why you're using LXDE/Lubuntu*), you'll find the older GA stack of 20.04 (*which was the HWE stack on 18.04*) maybe the *easy* answer; eg. `uname -r` & look at kernel; 5.4 is GA for 20.04 (& was HWE for 18.04), 5.15 is HWE for 20.04.. so switching kernel stack maybe an *easy* fix if using older hardware.. but that won't fix any *broken* desktop issues..  *Live* 20.04 media can be used to *test* 20.04 on your hardware...

Comment: Lubuntu is a *flavor* built on the base Ubuntu platform.  It was your base Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system that was offering the desktop, but Ubuntu upgrade instructions also warned you not to accept upgrade if offered with Lubuntu installed (*but the many & long Upgrade Notices need to be read via browser not being offered on screen when you receive the upgrade offers*). If you box is rather old; I'd explore the GA kernel stack using *live* media first by booting it (no installs required) you'll have a clue if it works if you're using the HWE stack currently; GA is the 5.4 kernel used on 18.04

Comment: You also have the 8168 NIC chipset and Ubuntu by default installs the 8169 driver which is very flaky with the 8168 chipset.  Install the `r8168-dkms` driver.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I truly appreciate your support. I'm currently getting as much of me files as I can and will be starting over using Ubuntu in the future.

Comment: I started with a fresh install.  removed the partition from my hard drive and used a Ubuntu 22.04 live DVD to reinstall Linux. I still have no internet unless I use USB tethering. her are the results from

Comment: After a clean install and tethering my phone to my PC with a USB cable. I ran the following commands. Everything seems to be working. Fixed my Ethernet connection, printer/scanner.
'apt-get install r8169-dkms'  {no output}
'apt-get install r8168-dkms'  {modprobe: FATAL: Module r8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic}
'sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms'  {0 upgraded, 47 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 199 MB of archives.
After this operation, 653 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y}
Thank you everyone